# how to compare voice with list in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, voice-recognition, voice

here is my code I'm using pocketsphinx I want to compare my voice with these words but it's not working.

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
import speech_recognition as sr
'''The start of Speech system is here,'''

def chair_offline():
    words = ["LEFT","RIGHT","FORWARD","BACKWARD","STOP","RUN"]
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    for audioo in LiveSpeech():
        res = str(audioo)
        if res in words:
            print(res)
        else:
            print("sorry modle not train")

chair_offline()
```

Comment: it's not working is not a really good description of the problem, can you tell us what exactly fails, any errors etc.

Comment: it take other words as a command mean if some body say "Hi" the program take it as a command and display it like "run".